# 16-bit parallel TFT LCD + Esp32 | white screen problem

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, lcd

It's originally for mega2560 but i want to run it with my esp32 microcontroller.
I've been working to make this work but it's just sits there an just looking my face with a white screen.. :/

**Microcontroller:** Esp32-wroom-32d
**LCD:** [3.5" - 320x480 - 16bit parallel - 65k colour - TFT LCD - Direct Support w/Mega2560](http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_Arduino_Display-Mega2560)

**Wiring:**

```
DB0   =>  GPIO15 | RS  => GPIO25
DB1   =>  GPIO2  | WR  => GPIO26
DB2   =>  GPIO0  | CS  => GPIO33
DB3   =>  GPIO4  | RST => GPIO32
DB4   =>  GPIO16
DB5   =>  GPIO17      
DB6   =>  GPIO5        
DB7   =>  GPIO18
DB8   =>  GPIO19  
DB9   =>  GPIO21 
DB10  =>  GPIO13  
DB11  =>  GPIO12  
DB12  =>  GPIO22
DB13  =>  GPIO23
DB14  =>  GPIO14
DB15  =>  GPIO27
```

I tried TFT-eSP, UTFT-ESP and the one lcdwiki mentions (module package).
And also tried to edit them to support my combo but nope, none of them work;
i uploaded the "lcdwiki" one to the github so you can see what i changed:
https://github.com/Herom123/tft-test/commit/143f8a218c5d346ded4f93f8f740ad1cd5ca46c3

i'm working on this about 4 days straight but nothing happened.. I was being really gentle with lcd so no damage nor i over voltage it. So it's probably because of the code but i can't find where the problem is :/ Can you guys help me out with this thing?

thanks in advance

the links used above:

[3.5" - 320x480 - 16bit parallel - 65k colour - TFT LCD - Direct Support w/Mega2560]: [www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_Arduino_Display-Mega2560](http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_Arduino_Display-Mega2560)
[TFT_eSPI]: github.com/Bodmer/TFT_eSPI
[UTFT-ESP]: github.com/gnulabis/UTFT-ESP
[lcdwiki mentions (module package)]: [www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_Arduino_Display-Mega2560](http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_Arduino_Display-Mega2560)

I want it to be at least draw a pixel so i can know that everything till there works.

Comment: Have you configured the SPI pins for the Select.h file inside the library?

Comment: @TashfiNowroz lcd screen is not support spi connection but 16bit parallel

Comment: Please don't take both `C++` and `C`, if you are using an Arduino framework, it is `C++`. Please don't include zip file (and no need to do it twice), no one will download unknown zip file. Please provides your code by copy and pasting it into your post.

Comment: i changed the tags. About the download thingy: it was on the lcdwiki and i directly pasted here so no trouble to find it but ig ill delete it

Comment: As we don't have the same hardware as you have, we can only suggest the steps to take for rectifying the issue. The easier way to confirm that all your macros are correctly set is to read the device ID (according to datasheet, it is a 3-byte data), once you can do that, you can then try to clear display (which consists of a lot writing into the display controller). If those can be done correctly, the rest should be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved :)

the answer is in this forum:
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/3-5-tft-ili9486-lcd-shield-16bit-parallel-320x480-esp32-white-screen/1069424?u=herom123